# technical name for web.xml and ejb.jar xml files?

Tags: xml

i'm having a problem in xml files.what is the technical name for the web.xml and ejb.jar xml files? and generational stages of garbage collection?
 that I had no idea

Online searching turned up, to my great surprise, nodda. Maybe this post can put an end to that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the technical name for the web.xml and ejb.jar xml files?

Answer (score 0):

web.xml is the Web Descriptor file.

ejb.jar is not an XML file .... so not sure what you are really asking here. It is the Java Archive for Enterprise Java Beans.